# AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict' - Fitting a List of train and test data

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying a NN model using this [example](http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/). I am fitting a list of values to a NN model. However, I am getting an `AttributeError`. This has been asked before and has been answered. Unfortunately, it is not working for me. As shown in the example, I created the following,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.layers import Dense

def neuralnetmodel():
    #Crete model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim = 13, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
## Output layer
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal'))

#Compile model
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
return model
```

`fit` training data,

```
NNmodelList = []

for i,j in zip(X_train_scaled,y_train): 
    nn_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn= neuralnetmodel, nb_epoch = 50, batch_size = 10, verbose = 0)
    NNmodelList.append(nn_model.fit(i,j))
```

`predict` from test data,

```
PredList = []
for val in X_test_scaled:
    for mod in NNmodelList: 
    pred = mod.predict(val)
PredList.append(pred)
```

Now, I am getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'

In previous [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622857/why-am-i-getting-attributeerror-kerasclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-mode) , it seems to be the train set was not `fit` to the model before `predict`. However, in mine, I fit them in the second code snippet. Any ideas what other possible mistakes I am making?

Comment: I found https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2379  this, I have my `model.compile` inside the function, which I guess is doing the job. Still can not wrap my head around, what other possible errors I am making.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

model.fit() does not return the Keras model, but a History object containing loss and metric values of your training. So in this code:

```
NNmodelList.append(nn_model.fit(i,j))
```

you're creating a list of History objects, not models. A simple fix would be:

```
NNmodelList.append(nn_model)
nn_model.fit(i,j)
```

Comment: thanks, this is working now, feel free to direct me to any resources that talks about this issue.

Comment: The Keras [docs](https://keras.io/) should have everything you need on the APIs and their usage.