# Keras AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

> **Note**: I have seen this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537372/attributeerror-history-object-has-no-attribute-predict-fitting-a-list-of) but I don't know I can use
>   the answer for my problem.

I try to use Keras for a simple regression. For this I have created a simple `policy_network()` function, which returns me the model.

```
def policy_network():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4),input_shape=[64,64,3]))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate),
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

    return model
```

I also have defined a global variable `policy_network`. I use the following assignment

```
policy_network = policy_network().fit(images, actions,
                  batch_size=256,
                  epochs=10,
                  shuffle=True)
```

but when I call

```
action = policy_network.predict(image)
```

I get the `AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras's `fit()` does **not** return the model but it returns a `History` object that contain per-epoch loss and metrics. The code pattern you are using will simply not work with Keras.

Do it like this:

```
model = policy_network()
model.fit(images, actions,
          batch_size=256,
          epochs=10,
          shuffle=True)
action = model.predict(image)
```

Answer (score 5):

You changed policy_network's class from a keras.Model object to History object when you said to Python

```
policy_network = policy_network().fit(..)
```

If you want to store History in a variable, store it in another variable:

```
history = policy_network.fit(..)
```

You can now use `policy_network.predict`, the way you want.