# Why am I getting "AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute '__call__'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Some one please clarify why I am getting attribute error for below code ?

````
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense 

def build_classifier():   #one of the parameter for KerasClassifier
    classifier = Sequential() #initialising ANN by defining sequence of layers
    classifier.add(Dense(units=6,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform',input_dim=11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=6,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
    #compiling the ANN
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
    return classifier

#fitting model for k-fold cross validation
classifier = KerasClassifier(buil_fn = build_classifier,nb_epochs = 100,
                            batch_size=10)  ```
````

Comment: similar issue --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622857/why-am-i-getting-attributeerror-kerasclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-mode/44623291

Comment: Please make sure the example actually runs (missing imports) and include the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `buil_fn` should be `build_fn`

Also, `nb_epochs` should be `nb_epoch`

```
#fitting model for k-fold cross validation
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier,nb_epoch = 100,
                            batch_size=10)
```